# Start two Play! application on same name server

Tags: apache, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to run two different web application on the same server, with the same domain name, like :

www.example.com/app1

www.example.com/app2

The applications are developed using Play! framework, and I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy. I tried to follow the online guide, set up the virtual host and etc..., but nothing seem to works, only the first app is reacheble, while the second isn't.

This is as far as I got untill now with my apache config file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  DocumentRoot "/home/App1/"
  ServerName http://www.example.com/app1
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/app1
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/app1
  LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  DocumentRoot "/home/App2"
  ServerName http://www.example.com/app2
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/app2
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/app2
  LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Route, code and everithing are correct, it's just that I can't get these apps work together.

(I also tried to implement the load balacer showed on the online guide, but it didn't work)

Thanks.

Comment: use subdomains instead, you'll life will become easier :)

Comment: that would be nice, but I can't get subdomains works. can yoou give me some help?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can have two virtual hosts with the same host name - that doesn't make sense, virtual hosts are for serving different host names, for example, for serving foo.example.com and bar.example.com.

I think what you want is something roughly like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /some/path/to/something
  ProxyPass  /excluded !

  ProxyPass /app1 http://127.0.0.1:9000/app1
  ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://127.0.0.1:9000/app1

  ProxyPass /app2 http://127.0.0.1:8000/app2
  ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://127.0.0.1:8000/app2

  LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

James' answer is correct, you just need to fit it to your needs, I shoot that works out of the box:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName www.example.com

    ProxyPass /app1 http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://127.0.0.1:9000/


    ProxyPass /app2 http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://127.0.0.1:8000/

 </VirtualHost>
```

Note, that you will need to prefix EVERY route in your apps to reflect the folder path with `app1` and `app2`, like:

```
<a href="app1@routes.Application.foo()">foo site</a>

<a href="app2@routes.Application.bar()">bar site</a>
```

Comment: I tried to implement this solution, but only the first app is reacheble, the second one never get hit.

Comment: and is it accessible via `127.0.0.1:8000` and/or `www.example.com:8000` ?

Comment: None of them is accessible.

Comment: So check your firewall or sth, it's hard to guess :/